# Axios post is not working inside react useeffect

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, frontend, use-effect

I am implementing a React app that tracks user activity. And I have a var named count and every time it changes I have to post it to my mongo using my api and react.
But the axios post isn't working inside *useeffect*. And I don't have a specific user driven event to stimulate post like *handlesubmit*.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const RealCount = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      chrome.storage.local.get("count", function(results) {
          setCount(results.count);
        });
      const newCount = {
        name: "axfg",
        count: count
      }
      axios.post("http://localhost:3000/create", newCount)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
}
```

But I checked my axios post in another function in another component and it is working perfectly.
Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const RealCount = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      chrome.storage.local.get("count", function(results) {
          setCount(results.count);
        });
      const newCount = {
        name: "axfg",
        count: count
      }
      (axios.post("http://localhost:3000/create", newCount)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        }))();
    }, [count]);
}
```

Comment: No, I tried it earlier, it wasn't working either.

Comment: I've updated and wrapped axios call in a IIFE. Can you check now ?

Comment: It's working Shravan. I made an awful mistake, I'm not using the real count component in my App.js. I have a duplicate of this code in another component and I'm using that. I discovered it just now when i try to create button inside this component.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue solved**
Guys, it was my mistake. I am not even using this component in my App.js. I am using a duplicate of this code in another component. That's why the changes didn't reflect in my program.